# Insertion Sort implementation in Java

Tags: java, optimization, sorting, insertion-sort

I have implemented Insertion sort in Java.  Please review it.

```
public class InsertionSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = new int[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            values[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (i!=0 && values[i] < values[i - 1]) {
                for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
                    System.out.println(" j"+j);
                    if (values[j] < values[j-1]) {
                        int temp = values[j - 1];
                        values[j - 1] = values[j];
                        values[j] = temp;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" sorted numbers");
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" "+values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider this:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
>     if (i!=0 && values[i] < values[i - 1]) {
> ```

`i` starts from 0, and then right after you use a condition `i!=0`. You could simplify to:

```
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i] < values[i - 1]) {
```

---

Consider this:

> ```
> if (values[i] < values[i - 1]) {
>     for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
>         if (values[j] < values[j - 1]) {
>             // ...
>         } else break;
> ```

Notice that `j` starts from `i`, and you have the same `if` immediately inside the loop, otherwise break. In other words, you don't need that outer `if`, because you run the same thing immediately inside the loop.

---

Consider this:

> ```
> for (int j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
>     if (values[j] < values[j - 1]) {
>         ...
>     } else break;
> ```

an equivalent but shorter and more traditional way to write the same thing:

```
for (int j = i; j >= 1 && values[j] < values[j - 1]; j--) {
    ...
}
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0 && values[j] < values[j - 1]; j--) {
        int temp = values[j - 1];
        values[j - 1] = values[j];
        values[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

We have arrived at the [pseudo algorithm of insertion sort in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) ;-)

---

I recommend using unit tests to check your implementations instead of printing text to the console and checking with your eyes. For example:

```
public Integer[] sort(Integer[] orig) {
    Integer[] values = orig.clone();
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && values[j] < values[j - 1]; j--) {
            int temp = values[j - 1];
            values[j - 1] = values[j];
            values[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    return values;
}

@Test
public void testExamples() {
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{3, 4, 5}, sort(new Integer[]{5, 4, 3}));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{3, 4, 5}, sort(new Integer[]{5, 3, 4}));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{3, 4, 5}, sort(new Integer[]{3, 5, 4}));
}
```

Running this is just as easy as running a main method. This approach also encourages decomposing your problems to elementary operations. In this case I had to extract the sorting logic to its own method to be easier to test. In the end, you will naturally have multiple methods, which is a good thing, at virtually no extra cost.